# Event at end of HTML5 video

Tags: wordpress, html, video

Can someone let me know if this is possible?
Thank you in advance for all your help.

- I am embedding HTML5 video in wordpress 5 page.
- I would like end of video to trigger a button to appear so people can move onto next video.

Button would only appear when video has finished playing...I was told there is onend event at the end of html5 video but not sure how to implement it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if your video is in < video > tags and you aren't opposed to using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('video').on('ended',function(){
  console.log('Video has ended!');
  // or make a button visible etc.
});
});
```